# Check if input fields contains certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find if what the user typing in to an input field contain certain text - I've kinda got it works, but only working for an exact match as opposed to a partial match. If a user types anything before the text i'm matching, of course the code doesn't trigger.

What i need to do is check if the input contains `@nyu.edu` at all in the input field.

```
$('.email').keyup(function(){
    if ($(".email").val() == "@nyu.edu") {
        $("p.warning").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else if ($(".email").val() != "@nyu.edu") {
        $("p.warning").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: the `else if( bla bla )` is not needed, use  simply `} else {` or a ternary operator, or a jQuery method like `.toggle()` that accepts a *boolean* argument.

Answer (score 4):

Checking if a string contains a substring is pretty easily done by taking `haystack.indexOf(needle)` and checking against `-1` (not found).

```
if ($(".email").val().indexOf("@nyu.edu") !== -1) {
    // contains
} else {
    // does not contain
}
```

---

There is a function in the *ES6* draft which you may find more natural, called `includes`

You can add support for *ES6's* [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) like this

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
    String.prototype.includes = function (needle, pos) {
        return this.indexOf(needle, pos || 0) !== -1;
    };
}

"foobar".includes('foo'); // true
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan IE8 and _the internet_ are not friends.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Also according to Microsoft, the _String_ version of `indexOf` [**works in IE6+**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx) as does `obj.prototype` in [**IE6+**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/f5s9ycex%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) (see requirements sections)

Comment: **.includes** or **.contains** does the same

Comment: @Edwin The _ES6 Draft_ currently uses [`String.prototype.includes`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.includes) because of a signature conflict with a previous version of MooTools

Answer (score 0):

**Working Ex:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJKMjo

```
$('.email').keyup(function() {
    var exp = /@nyu\.edu$/; // reg ex
    var input = $(this).val(); // email input
    var matches = exp.test(input); // boolean
    // changes to hidden or visible
    $("p.warning").css("visibility", (matches) ? "visible" : "hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on HTML elements' attribute contents with jQuery to either contain, start, or end with a string that you want. To match elements with an attribute that contain a string, you'd use [`[attr*="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) in your jQuery selector, but I think that you want something where the end matches your string. Here's how that would work:

```
var elements = $(".email[value$='@nyu.edu']");
if(elements.length > 0) {
    // Do something with the elements, such as removing an .error class
} else {
    // Email doesn't end with @nyu.edu
}
```

Read more about the [jQuery ends-with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) or [browse through other attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) like this.

Comment: nonono Watch out running across the whole DOM tree starching for a *low-speed* selector like `.email[value$='@nyu.edu']` on every key event...

Comment: also read more about the `$=` slector. no-one guarantees you that astring will end exactly with that value.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It clearly filters elements with the class `email` first, which is exactly what the other recommended answers do. And where on earth do you see that this isn't guaranteed?

Comment: How you mean *`"And where on earth do you see that this isn't guaranteed?"`* ? If I copy-pasted an email address along with an ending *WhiteSpace* your script will **Fail-On-Earth**. That Earth? (Don't take suggestions so personally. Rather think about the issues and improve :) )

Comment: I don't see how I'm taking anything personally lol, but now that you make yourself clear, did you read the entire answer I posted? The first thing I talked about was the `[attr*="value"]` attribute selector.

Answer (score -1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kinaye/4/edit)***

```
var $warning = $("p.warning"); // P.S. make sure not to target a wrong .warning!
$('.email').on("input", function(){
    $warning.toggle( /@nyu\.edu/ig.test(this.value) );
});
```

as I've mentioned `.warning` being a class can represent *any* first `.warning` occurrence. use rather some other selector like `.next()` or `.closest(selector).find(".warning")`

your boss fill fire you if your client loses $$$ cause you forgot to watch for **copy-paste** cases. ;) Kidding, use `"input"` event.

P.S use `.warning{display:none;}` instead of `visibility`

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex and "@nyu@edu" will match which is definitely undesirable. Moreover in your example, as soon as someone types in anything with "@nyu.edu", the warning will show. As long as it's incorrect, the warning will stay hidden.