# Check if user input number contains a commas in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking and trying many things for this but didn't find any solution that worked:(

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536581/check-if-input-fields-contains-certain-text) for example didn't work and many others.

I want to look if there's a simple commas in the user input, I've tried with `.val().indexOf(",") !== -1` and a bunch of other stuff, but doesn't work.

Here's my Jquery code:

```
$("#add_btn").click(function(e) {
            $("#alert_msg").hide().empty();
            e.preventDefault();
            var err = 0;
            if ($("input[name=product_type]#add_type").val() == "") {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré un <div>type</div> valide!</div>');
                err++;
            } else if ($("input[name=product_brand]#add_brand").val() == "") {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré une <div>marque</div> valide!</div>');
                err++;
            } else if ($("textarea[name=product_description]#add_description").val() == "") {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré une <div>description</div>!</div>');
                err++;
            } else if ($("input[name=product_r_price]#add_reg_price").val() == "") {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré un <div>prix</div> valide!</div>');
                err++;
            } else if ($("input[name=product_r_price]#add_reg_price").val().indexOf(",") !== -1) {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré un <div>prix11</div> valide!</div>');
                err++;
            } else if ($("input[name=product_modele]#add_model").val() == "") {
                $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré un numéro de <div>model</div>!</div>');
                err++;
            } else {
                err = 0;
            }

            if (err == 0) {
                $("#add_product_form").submit();
            }
        });
```

Here's what the input looks like, just in case:

```
<input id='add_reg_price' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='Prix rég.' name='product_r_price'>
```

Thank you!

**EDIT, I'm checking if this input has a commas or not:

```
else if ($("input[name=product_r_price]#add_reg_price").val().indexOf(",") !== -1) {
                    $("#alert_msg").css('display', 'flex').append('<div>Vous devez entré un <div>prix11</div> valide!</div>');
                    err++;
                }
```

Comment: The user simply can not enter a coma in an `input type="number`... So why checking for this error possibility? -- By the way, you have a conjugation mistake on `devez entré`, which should be `devez entrer` ;)

Comment: uhm yhea but they can still enter "," for the price! And what the heck, you're a french speaker too? xD